# How can i navigate from a screen inside a DrawerNavigator to an other one inside the same DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When my user update his email adress (inside ChangeMail screen)  i would like to redirect him to the first screen of the DrawerNavigator: 'Exercices'

I don't understand hos this.props.navigation works in this case.

```
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Exercices: {
        screen: stackNavigator
    },
    ResetPassword: {
        screen: ResetPassword
    },
    ChangeMail: {
        screen: ChangeMail
    },
    DeleteAccount: {
        screen: DeleteAccount
    },
    Disconnect: {
        screen: ExitScreen
    }
})
```

```js
//inside the ChangeMail screen
changeEmail = (currentPassword, newEmail) => {
        this.reauthenticate(currentPassword).then(() => {
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            user.updateEmail(newEmail).then(() => {
                console.log("Email updated!");
            }).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
        }).catch((error) => { console.log(error); }).then(() => {
            updateDatabaseEmail(newEmail)
        }).then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Exercice"))
          //not working

    }
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route name is `Exercices` but you are navigating to `Exercice`

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Exercices")
```